# Alternative syntax to apply several css rules conditionally in an angular template?

Tags: angular, angular-template

I want to conditional apply an inline style with multiples css rules inside (with all the rules relying on one condition only).

Most of the time, I will want to turn
**(1)**:

```
<div style="color: gray; opacity: 0.8"></div>
```

to **(2)**:

```
<div [ngStyle]="(condition) ? {'color': 'gray', 'opacity': '0.8'} : {}"></div>
```

And often (but not always), I might want to refactor into an external css file, and add the class as needed,
**(3)**:

```
.my-class {
    color: gray;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Is there a syntax for the step 2 that might be more similar than 1 and 3 (to avoid the useless refactoring of css string: `'color: gray; opacity: 0.8;'` into `'color': 'gray', 'opacity': '0.8'`).

Something close to:

```
<div {{ condition | styleIf:'color: gray; opacity 0.8' }}></div>
```

I know it's not *that* bad, but slightly inconvenient and awkward refactor dance.
If not, I'm planning to write a pipe, but I would prefer to ask before re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't hesitant to play with styles in your ts file you can try the following.

In your template:

```
<div [ngStyle]="customStyleObject()">My Content</div>
```

Define the function in your component to return the style.

```
customStyleObject(): Object {
    if (<your condition here>) {
      return { color: "yellow", opacity: 0.8, background: "red" };
    }
    return {};
}
```

You could return a string, array or object as above as per your needs.

Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngstyle-examples-j6n3zh?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

you can has one variable

```
customStyle={
    color: gray,
    opacity: 0.8
}
```

And use

```
<div [ngStyle]="condition?customStyle:null">my div</div>
//or
<div [class.my-class]="condition">my div</div>
```

Well, you can has another variable

```
applyclass:boolean=false
```

and write some so "bizarro" as

```
<div [ngStyle]="condition && !applyclass?customStyle:null" [class.my-class]="condition && aplyclass">
   My Content
</div>
```